# How to expand the div container of ul and li?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have a div with its content (list inside),

```
<div id="container">
     <ul id="list">
       <li>
         <div class="title">
              something
         </div>
         <div class="text">
             something again
         </div>
       </li>
        <li>
         <div class="title">
              something
         </div>
         <div class="text">
             something again
         </div>
       </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And my items from list are displayed `float:left`, and I want to the div container expand in height as its content.

```
#container{ 
    position: relative; 
    width: 100%;    
    padding-bottom: 30px;       
}

#list{
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 80px;
    width: 95%;
    /*height: 100%;*/
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#list li{
    position: relative;
    float: left;    
    list-style: none outside none;
    width: 20%;
    height: 170px;  
    /*border:1px solid black;*/
}
```

Comment: some like expand menu ?

Comment: So where is the `float: left;` in your CSS? You are missing a closing angle bracket (`>`) off your `#container` div by the way.

Comment: Please show a more complete example of your code. If possible create a jsfiddle so that we can see what the problem is.

Comment: Its more like, I have that Div, container, and, my list has 13 elements. And for instance, my container has background-color: red; and I want that div container expand based on its 13 elements. I have 5-5-3 .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have several options:

1. [Clearfix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554043/what-is-clearfix) on the container:

   ```
   #container:after {
       clear: both;
       content: "";
       display: table;
   }
   ```
2. [The use](http://colinaarts.com/articles/the-magic-of-overflow-hidden/) of `overflow`:

   ```
   #container {
       overflow: hidden; /* or: auto | scroll */
   }
   ```
3. Float the container:

   ```
   #container {
       float: left;
   }
   ```
4. Using `inline-block` instead of `float` for the list items:

   ```
   #container ul li {
       display: inline-block;
       float: none;
   }
   ```

Comment: I think it was the "overflow:hidden", because now its working :)

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach...

```
li {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none; /* only if you have this set as you mentioned in your post */
}

#container {
  height: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but as I said above, i think my "overflow:hidden" was missing. :)